# Analyse MySQL General Query Log in Real-time?

Tags: mysql, log

We want to use mysql general query log to do real-time monitoring and auditing.

Currently our approach is:

- set general_log=on;
- sleep 15m;
- set general_log=off;
- scp & rm xxx.log;
- set general_log=on;...

But the main problem is when turn on/off general log it'll cause a peak of slow query.

I also thought of another approach: turn on genlog; tail -f it and send out the log; periodically truncate the logfile (with "> xxx.log" or "cat /dev/null >xxx.log").

I'm wondering whether it's practical.

If only mysql would provide some built-in general log message queue stuff...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are really interesting in monitoring via the general log, there are two major approaches you can try:

## APPROACH #1 : Rotating Logs

Let's say you have the following configuration in `my.cnf`:

```
[mysqld]
general-log
general-log-file=/var/log/mysql_general.log
```

You could rotate the general log with the following script:

```
MYSQL_CONN="-uroot -prootpassword"
DT=`date +"%Y%m%d"`
OLDLOG=mysql_general_${DT}.log
cd /var/log
mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -e"SET GLOBAL general_log = 'OFF';"
cp mysql_general.log ${OLDLOG}
echo -n > mysql_general.log
mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -e"SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';"
```

As for your monitoring, you would scan the text file as you already do. You can always look back at previous copies of the general.log as archives.

## APPROACH #2 : Make the General Log a MyISAM table

Try setting up the general log as MyISAM.

First let's configure the table for logging to tables

```
[mysqld]
general-log
log-output=TABLE
```

Next, MySQL supplies the table `mysql.general_log`. It looks like this:

```
mysql> show create table mysql.general_log\G 
*************************** 1. row *************************** 
       Table: general_log 
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `general_log` ( 
  `event_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
  `user_host` mediumtext NOT NULL, 
  `thread_id` int(11) NOT NULL, 
  `server_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL, 
  `command_type` varchar(64) NOT NULL, 
  `argument` mediumtext NOT NULL 
) ENGINE=CSV DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='General log'
```

Of course, the general log as a [CSV table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/csv-storage-engine.html) is hardly useful. You can do two things:

- Turn it into a MyISAM table
- Index it however you need, starting with the `event_time`

Here is that code:

```
SET @old_log_state = @@global.general_log; 
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'OFF'; 
ALTER TABLE mysql.general_log ENGINE = MyISAM; 
ALTER TABLE mysql.general_log ADD INDEX (event_time); 
SET GLOBAL general_log = @old_log_state;
```

When the smoke clears, `mysql.general_log` now looks like this:

```
mysql> show create table general_log\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: general_log
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `general_log` (
  `event_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `user_host` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `thread_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `server_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `command_type` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `argument` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  KEY `event_time` (`event_time`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='General log'
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Events get recorded in this table instead of the text file. Naturally, you want to rotate this as well. Here is that script

```
SCRIPT=/tmp/rotate_general_log_table.sql
MYSQL_CONN="-uroot -prootpassword"
DT=`date +"%Y%m%d"`
OLDLOG=general_log_${DT}
echo "SET GLOBAL general_log = 'OFF';" > ${SCRIPT}
echo "ALTER TABLE mysql.general_log RENAME mysql.${OLDLOG};" >> ${SCRIPT}
echo "CREATE TABLE mysql.general_log LIKE mysql.${OLDLOG};" >> ${SCRIPT}
echo "SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';" >> ${SCRIPT}
mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} < ${SCRIPT}
```

As for your monitoring, you would query the `mysql.general_log` table like this:

```
SELECT * FROM mysql.general_log WHERE argument LIKE '...';
```

Perhaps yo u may want to check the last 4 hours

```
SELECT * FROM mysql.general_log
WHERE event_time >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 4 HOUR)
AND argument LIKE '...';
```

## CAVEAT

If you want both the text file and the table, then configure them both like this:

```
[mysqld]
general-log
general-log-file=/var/log/mysql_general.log
log-output=TABLE,FILE
```

Of course, you would have to implement the rotation of both.

I have written other past posts about `mysql.general_log`:

- `Apr 04, 2013` : [Stress test MySQL with queries captured with general log in MySQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39221/stress-test-mysql-with-queries-captured-with-general-log-in-mysql/39285#39285)
- `Feb 11, 2012` : [MySQL general log](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12667/mysql-general-log/12672#12672)
- `Jan 08, 2012` : [How to enable MySQL general log?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10329/how-to-enable-mysql-general-log/10346#10346)
- `Jun 30, 2011` : [How do I output MySQL logs to syslog?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3552/how-do-i-output-mysql-logs-to-syslog/3571#3571)

## Give it a Try !!!

Comment: I see another post of yours, saying tail and send out the general log, and truncate the log file at midnight. I'm wondering whether this "echo -n > general.log" operation will do any harm to mysql, or result in corrupted general log format? e.g. truncate when mysql is still logging into it, so there's only half of the statement, etc.

Comment: I do this for some clients now. This technique works well, especially when shut off the general log to do the switch. Truncating a disabled general log is trivial. The harm is eliminated. You should make sure the log does not get too big or the "echo -n" trick will take a bit of time. That's why I also suggest approach #2 for a quick switch and making the general log immediately svailable and operational.